# How to apply security policy on a table which depends information of inner join table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to implement Row Level Security to my Database. In my database there are 2 table. First table consist id,name and status column. Status column is used to determine the level of a record. Second table consist wage,time and user_id column.

**User Table**

| id | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | james | non-vip |
| 11 | mark | vip |
| 12 | edward | non-vip |

Note: id is unique

**Wage Table**

| userid | wage | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 100 | jan |
| 11 | 500 | jan |
| 12 | 250 | jan |

Normally when i run for "select * from wagetable where wage > 200" this query, it will return record 11 and 12. However i want that vip people's wage shouldn't be seen by HR analysts. To accomplish this task i will create a security policy on wage table but in wage table i dont have the information of status. I only have user code. How can i overcome this problem ?

Comment: Create a view with row-level security; this view joins the tables and filter out rows according you your logic. You'll need, of course, to remove read access to the underlying table(s). The new view may even reside in a different schema.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've solved the problem.By creating a view and applying policy on the view.

Firstly i have created a view inner joins the wage table with user table to obtain user's status information.

Secondly i defined a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_RowLevelSecurity] (@status varchar(50))    
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
RETURN SELECT 1 as fn_SecureData
Where @status = user_name()
```

And Finally i applied security policy by using function to my view.

```
CREATE SECURITY POLICY RowFilter
ADD FILTER PREDICATE dbo.fn_RowLevelSecurity(status) 
ON dbo.MyView
WITH (STATE = ON);
```

Comment: Could you add some additional details to help clarify your solution for future readers with a similar problem?