# How to know if my security policy filtered and removed some rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a Row Level Security policy in my recent post. [Creating Row Level Security in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69377315/how-to-apply-security-policy-on-a-table-which-depends-information-of-inner-join). Now I need to learn the information which is my filter removed some rows or it didn't have an effect on the query?

Example;

**User Table**

| id | name | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | james | non-vip |
| 11 | mark | vip |
| 12 | edward | non-vip |

Note: id is unique

**Wage Table**

| userid | wage | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 100 | jan |
| 11 | 500 | jan |
| 12 | 250 | jan |

For this example my Row Level Security filter will filter the userid 11 result to non-vip queryable users. But I want additional information which is my filter have effect on my query or not?

For query "select * from wage where wage > 200", Desired Result: Yes Filter Applied

For query "select * from wage where wage <200", Desired Result: No Filter have no effect on this query because there is no vip user who earns lower then 200.

Comment: Can you think of why this might be bad, if it were possible?

Comment: @AakashM Actually i just want to warn user by giving information which is "your query contains some information that user do not have permission to see."

Comment: This would allow people to deduce the information without much problem. You could just run queries like `select * from wage where userid=11 and wage > x and wage < y` to zero in on hidden information and then narrow the range to deduce exact salaries

Comment: @MartinSmith Do not assume that is real work. This is just and example. In real work there will be strings or other non guessable columns. By the way they will only obtain the amount of wage not the user data. Also my security policy restrict user to get userid of 11.